# input[type="range"] selector isn't working in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-7

I have several range inputs that I have to make consistent across browsers so I am using jQuery UI slider for them. The problem is not with that part, but actually with getting those elements.

This is how the inputs look:

```
<input type="range" name="..." value="..." min="..." max="..." />
```

Selecting them with `input[type="range"]` works in every browse besides IE7 (IE8 is fine). The code should run on Wordpress 3.1, so I have to use jQuery 1.4.

I've currently solved it by adding a class to the range inputs and that works fine, but I was wondering what is the problem with this selector in IE7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE7 and lower will automatically convert to `type="text"`. Try this and you will see

```
alert($('input').attr('type')); // alerts "text"
```

Therefore your selector doesn't match.

You could add `data-type` instead of a class only for jQuery selection

```
<input data-type="range" type="range" name="..." value="..." min="..." max="..." />
```

and use

```
$('input[data-type="range"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

IE 7 supports a limited set of [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html). Furthermore, it probably doesn't recognize `input type="range"`.

Answer (score 0):

ie7 like ie6 has become an obsolete browser so you should not be expecting it to support `type=range`.